# How to backup a Azure Data Lake Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

How do I backup an Azure storage account that has hierarchical namespace enabled (and is a Data Lake storage account)?

Under "Data mangement", I have very limited "Data protection" options because of it being a Data Lake account. "Lifecycle management" also doesn't provide option to "copy" the blob. Instead, it only has options to "move" a blob.

Please note that my question is only for "Data Lake" storage accounts and NOT the standard blob storage accounts.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Azure doesn't provide a built-in backup solution specifically tailored for ADLS Gen2.

Using ADF, you can set up a data copy activity to copy data from your source ADLS Gen2 account to a destination, such as another ADLS Gen2 account or even another type of storage and schedule it to run at specific intervals

If you want to backup for DR, Consider enabling geo-redundant storage (GRS) or geo-zone-redundant storage (GZRS) for your ADLS Gen2 account.This ensures that your data is replicated to a secondary region (hundreds of miles away from the primary region).

Comment: By "data copy activity" you mean manually set up a Cron to `azcopy` from one storage account to another backup storage account or there's an optoin in Azure portal to do that?

Comment: Use Azure Data Factory, Azure Data Factory has a data copy activity. You can also run azcopy at scheduled times also which is different approach from Azure Data Factory data copy activity.